# In tm package, remove all numbers except alphanumeric characters

Tags: r, tm, alphanumeric

In r, I'm trying to keep words like `3g`, `4g`, `4s`, etc. in my corpus when removing numbers while using the `tm` package.

When using `removeNumbers` how can I preserve alphanumeric characters like `3g`, `4g`, `4s`, etc.? In other words, any digits that is together with another letter is to be preserved. Does anyone know of an alternative function that I could use if a custom function needs to be used instead?

```
examp1 <- "When 222 discussing performance 4g with colleagues, teaching, sending a bug report or searching for 55 guidance on mailing lists and here on SO, a reproducible example is often asked and 3g always helpful. What are your tips for creating an 333 excellent 444 example? How do you paste data structures from r in a text format? What other 443 galaxy 4s information should you include? Are there other tricks in addition to using dput(), dump() or structure()? When should you include library() or require() statements? Which reserved words should one avoid, in addition to c, df, data, etc? How does one make a great r reproducible example?"
examp2 <- "Sometimes the problem 24K really isn't reproducible with a smaller piece of data, no matter how hard you try, and doesn't happen with synthetic data (although it's useful to show how you produced synthetic data sets that did not reproduce the problem, because it rules out some hypotheses). Posting the data t 8888 the web somewhere and providing a URL may be necessary. If the data can't be released to the public at large but could be shared at all, then you may be able to offer to e-mail it to interested parties (although this will cut down the number of people who will bother to work on it). I haven't actually seen this 4444 done, because people who can't release their data are sensitive about releasing it any form, but it would seem plausible that in some cases one could still post data if it were sufficiently anonymized/scrambled/corrupted slightly in some way. If you can't do either of these then you probably need to hire a consultant to solve your problem" 
examp3 <- "You are 888 most 1g likely to get good 5g help with your R problem if you provide a reproducible example. A reproducible example allows someone else to recreate your problem by just copying and pasting R code. There are four things you need to include to make your example reproducible: required packages, data, code, and a description of your R environment. Packages should be loaded at the top of the script, so it's easy to see which ones the example needs. The easiest way to include data in an email is to use dput() to generate the R code to recreate it. For example, to recreate the mtcars dataset in R, I'd perform the following steps: Run dput(mtcars) in R Copy the output In my reproducible script, type mtcars <- then paste. Spend a little bit of time ensuring that your code is easy for others to read: make sure you've used spaces and your variable names are concise, but informative, use comments to indicate where your problem lies, do your best to remove everything that is not related to the problem. The shorter your code is, the easier it is to understand. Include the output of sessionInfo() as a comment. This summarises your R environment and makes it easy to check if you're using an out-of-date package. You can check you have actually made a reproducible example by starting up a fresh R session and pasting your script in. Before putting all of your code in an email, consider putting it on http://gist.github.com/. It will give your code nice syntax highlighting, and you don't have to worry about anything getting mangled by the email system."
examp4 <- "Do your homework before posting: If it is clear that you have done basic background research, you are far more likely to get an informative response. See also Further Resources further down this page. Do help.search(keyword) and apropos(keyword) with different keywords (type this at the R prompt). Do RSiteSearch(keyword) with different keywords (at the R prompt) to search R functions, contributed packages and R-Help postings. See ?RSiteSearch for further options and to restrict searches. Read the online help for relevant functions (type ?functionname, e.g., ?prod, at the R prompt) If something seems to have changed in R, look in the latest NEWS file on CRAN for information about it. Search the R-faq and the R-windows-faq if it might be relevant (http://cran.r-project.org/faqs.html) Read at least the relevant section in An Introduction to R If the function is from a package accompanying a book, e.g., the MASS package, consult the book before posting. The R Wiki has a section on finding functions and documentation"
examp5 <- "Before 6g asking a technical question by e-mail, or in a newsgroup, or on a website chat board, do the following:  Try to find an answer by searching the archives of the forum you plan to post to. Try to find an answer by searching the Web. Try to find an answer by reading the manual. Try to find an answer by reading a FAQ. Try to find an answer by inspection or experimentation. Try to find an answer by asking a skilled friend. If you're a programmer, try to find an answer by reading the source code. When you ask your question, display the fact that you have done these things first; this will help establish that you're not being a lazy sponge and wasting people's time. Better yet, display what you have learned from doing these things. We like answering questions for people who have demonstrated they can learn from the answers. Use tactics like doing a Google search on the text of whatever error message you get (searching Google groups as well as Web pages). This might well take you straight to fix documentation or a mailing list thread answering your question. Even if it doesn't, saying “I googled on the following phrase but didn't get anything that looked promising” is a good thing to do in e-mail or news postings requesting help, if only because it records what searches won't help. It will also help to direct other people with similar problems to your thread by linking the search terms to what will hopefully be your problem and resolution thread. Take your time. Do not expect to be able to solve a complicated problem with a few seconds of Googling. Read and understand the FAQs, sit back, relax and give the problem some thought before approaching experts. Trust us, they will be able to tell from your questions how much reading and thinking you did, and will be more willing to help if you come prepared. Don't instantly fire your whole arsenal of questions just because your first search turned up no answers (or too many). Prepare your question. Think it through. Hasty-sounding questions get hasty answers, or none at all. The more you do to demonstrate that having put thought and effort into solving your problem before seeking help, the more likely you are to actually get help. Beware of asking the wrong question. If you ask one that is based on faulty assumptions, J. Random Hacker is quite likely to reply with a uselessly literal answer while thinking Stupid question..., and hoping the experience of getting what you asked for rather than what you needed will teach you a lesson."


corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(c(examp1, examp2, examp3, examp4)))


# How can I remove numbers except for numbers with words (1g, 4g, etc.) so after doing so it would look like...


inspect(corpus)

    [1] "When discussing performance 4g with colleagues, teaching, sending a bug report or searching for guidance on mailing lists and here on SO, a reproducible example is often asked and 3g always helpful. What are your tips for creating an excellent example? How do you paste data structures from r in a text format? What other galaxy 4s information should you include? Are there other tricks in addition to using dput(), dump() or structure()? When should you include library() or require() statements? Which reserved words should one avoid, in addition to c, df, data, etc? How does one make a great r reproducible example?"
    [2] "Sometimes the problem 24K really isn't reproducible with a smaller piece of data, no matter how hard you try, and doesn't happen with synthetic data (although it's useful to show how you produced synthetic data sets that did not reproduce the problem, because it rules out some hypotheses). Posting the data t 8888 the web somewhere and providing a URL may be necessary. If the data can't be released to the public at large but could be shared at all, then you may be able to offer to e-mail it to interested parties (although this will cut down the number of people who will bother to work on it). I haven't actually seen this done, because people who can't release their data are sensitive about releasing it any form, but it would seem plausible that in some cases one could still post data if it were sufficiently anonymized/scrambled/corrupted slightly in some way. If you can't do either of these then you probably need to hire a consultant to solve your problem" 
    [3] "You are most 1g likely to get good 5g help with your R problem if you provide a reproducible example. A reproducible example allows someone else to recreate your problem by just copying and pasting R code. There are four things you need to include to make your example reproducible: required packages, data, code, and a description of your R environment. Packages should be loaded at the top of the script, so it's easy to see which ones the example needs. The easiest way to include data in an email is to use dput() to generate the R code to recreate it. For example, to recreate the mtcars dataset in R, I'd perform the following steps: Run dput(mtcars) in R Copy the output In my reproducible script, type mtcars <- then paste. Spend a little bit of time ensuring that your code is easy for others to read: make sure you've used spaces and your variable names are concise, but informative, use comments to indicate where your problem lies, do your best to remove everything that is not related to the problem. The shorter your code is, the easier it is to understand. Include the output of sessionInfo() as a comment. This summarises your R environment and makes it easy to check if you're using an out-of-date package. You can check you have actually made a reproducible example by starting up a fresh R session and pasting your script in. Before putting all of your code in an email, consider putting it on http://gist.github.com/. It will give your code nice syntax highlighting, and you don't have to worry about anything getting mangled by the email system."
    [4] "Do your homework before posting: If it is clear that you have done basic background research, you are far more likely to get an informative response. See also Further Resources further down this page. Do help.search(keyword) and apropos(keyword) with different keywords (type this at the R prompt). Do RSiteSearch(keyword) with different keywords (at the R prompt) to search R functions, contributed packages and R-Help postings. See ?RSiteSearch for further options and to restrict searches. Read the online help for relevant functions (type ?functionname, e.g., ?prod, at the R prompt) If something seems to have changed in R, look in the latest NEWS file on CRAN for information about it. Search the R-faq and the R-windows-faq if it might be relevant (http://cran.r-project.org/faqs.html) Read at least the relevant section in An Introduction to R If the function is from a package accompanying a book, e.g., the MASS package, consult the book before posting. The R Wiki has a section on finding functions and documentation"
    [5] "Before 6g asking a technical question by e-mail, or in a newsgroup, or on a website chat board, do the following:  Try to find an answer by searching the archives of the forum you plan to post to. Try to find an answer by searching the Web. Try to find an answer by reading the manual. Try to find an answer by reading a FAQ. Try to find an answer by inspection or experimentation. Try to find an answer by asking a skilled friend. If you're a programmer, try to find an answer by reading the source code. When you ask your question, display the fact that you have done these things first; this will help establish that you're not being a lazy sponge and wasting people's time. Better yet, display what you have learned from doing these things. We like answering questions for people who have demonstrated they can learn from the answers. Use tactics like doing a Google search on the text of whatever error message you get (searching Google groups as well as Web pages). This might well take you straight to fix documentation or a mailing list thread answering your question. Even if it doesn't, saying “I googled on the following phrase but didn't get anything that looked promising” is a good thing to do in e-mail or news postings requesting help, if only because it records what searches won't help. It will also help to direct other people with similar problems to your thread by linking the search terms to what will hopefully be your problem and resolution thread. Take your time. Do not expect to be able to solve a complicated problem with a few seconds of Googling. Read and understand the FAQs, sit back, relax and give the problem some thought before approaching experts. Trust us, they will be able to tell from your questions how much reading and thinking you did, and will be more willing to help if you come prepared. Don't instantly fire your whole arsenal of questions just because your first search turned up no answers (or too many). Prepare your question. Think it through. Hasty-sounding questions get hasty answers, or none at all. The more you do to demonstrate that having put thought and effort into solving your problem before seeking help, the more likely you are to actually get help. Beware of asking the wrong question. If you ask one that is based on faulty assumptions, J. Random Hacker is quite likely to reply with a uselessly literal answer while thinking Stupid question..., and hoping the experience of getting what you asked for rather than what you needed will teach you a lesson."
```

Comment: How do we determine what words to keep? Is it any digits that is together with another letter is to be preserved, or you have just a set of select combinations eg `3g`above to be kept, but `9g`to be removed?

Comment: @Ricky Any digits that is together with another letter is to be preserved.

Comment: Do you have the original text in other format before converting into your corpus? If so, my guess is it may be easiest to remove all the numbers before converting the documents into your corpus.

Comment: It's in a data frame. Still, I'd like to keep any digits together with another letter so I don't necessarily want remove all the numbers (i.e. numbers with digits). Would you know how to do so within a data frame @Ricky?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple gsub with a regex pattern. I suspect that it may fail with real data, but since you provided basically nothing to test this on, this seems a reasonable place to start

```
> gsub("([ ,.])([[:digit:]. ]+)([ ,.])", "\\1\\3", c('3g 44 999 4g 4s 555 42.') )
[1] "3g  4g 4s ."
```

This applies that strategy to a Corpus:

```
> modcorp <- lapply(corpus, function(cp) { cp[['content']] <- gsub("([ ,.])([[:digit:]. ]+)([ ,.])", "\\1\\3", cp[['content']] ); return(cp) }
+ )
> str(modcorp)
List of 4
 $ 1:List of 2
  ..$ content: chr "When  discussing performance 4g with colleagues, teaching, sending a bug report or searching for  guidance on mailing lists and"| __truncated__
  ..$ meta   :List of 7
  .. ..$ author       : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ datetimestamp: POSIXlt[1:1], format: "2015-11-09 18:05:27"
  .. ..$ description  : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ heading      : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ id           : chr "1"
  .. ..$ language     : chr "en"
  .. ..$ origin       : chr(0) 
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "TextDocumentMeta"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "PlainTextDocument" "TextDocument"
 $ 2:List of 2
  ..$ content: chr "Sometimes the problem 24K really isn't reproducible with a smaller piece of data, no matter how hard you try, and doesn't happe"| __truncated__
  ..$ meta   :List of 7
  .. ..$ author       : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ datetimestamp: POSIXlt[1:1], format: "2015-11-09 18:05:27"
  .. ..$ description  : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ heading      : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ id           : chr "2"
  .. ..$ language     : chr "en"
  .. ..$ origin       : chr(0) 
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "TextDocumentMeta"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "PlainTextDocument" "TextDocument"
 $ 3:List of 2
  ..$ content: chr "You are  most 1g likely to get good 5g help with your R problem if you provide a reproducible example. A reproducible example a"| __truncated__
  ..$ meta   :List of 7
  .. ..$ author       : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ datetimestamp: POSIXlt[1:1], format: "2015-11-09 18:05:27"
  .. ..$ description  : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ heading      : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ id           : chr "3"
  .. ..$ language     : chr "en"
  .. ..$ origin       : chr(0) 
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "TextDocumentMeta"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "PlainTextDocument" "TextDocument"
 $ 4:List of 2
  ..$ content: chr "Do your homework before posting: If it is clear that you have done basic background research, you are far more likely to get an"| __truncated__
  ..$ meta   :List of 7
  .. ..$ author       : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ datetimestamp: POSIXlt[1:1], format: "2015-11-09 18:05:27"
  .. ..$ description  : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ heading      : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ id           : chr "4"
  .. ..$ language     : chr "en"
  .. ..$ origin       : chr(0) 
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "TextDocumentMeta"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "PlainTextDocument" "TextDocument"
```

Comment: See the example I posted. How could I preserve any digits that is together with another letter in a corpus? @42-

Answer (score 1):

Try the **quanteda** package, it knows the difference between alphanumeric and numeric.  E.g.

```
> quanteda::tokenize("You are 888 most 1g likely to get gr8 help with your 24K R problem.",
+                    removePunct = TRUE, removeNumbers = TRUE)
tokenizedText object from 1 document.
Component 1 :
 [1] "You"     "are"     "most"    "1g"      "likely"  "to"      "get"     "gr8"     "help"   
[10] "with"    "your"    "24K"     "R"       "problem"
```

`removeNumbers` only removes numbers, not *digits*.  You can create a corpus directly from texts using `quanteda::corpus()`, or from a **tm** VCorpus or, as in the example above, tokenise directly on a character (vector) object.

Added:

If you want to return a tm TermDocumentMatrix, wrap it up like this:

```
examp <-  c("When 222 discussing performance 4g with colleagues, teaching, sending a bug report or searching for 55 guidance on mailing lists and here on SO, a reproducible example is often asked and 3g always helpful. What are your tips for creating an 333 excellent 444 example? How do you paste data structures from r in a text format? What other 443 galaxy 4s information should you include? Are there other tricks in addition to using dput(), dump() or structure()? When should you include library() or require() statements? Which reserved words should one avoid, in addition to c, df, data, etc? How does one make a great r reproducible example?",
            "Sometimes the problem 24K really isn't reproducible with a smaller piece of data, no matter how hard you try, and doesn't happen with synthetic data (although it's useful to show how you produced synthetic data sets that did not reproduce the problem, because it rules out some hypotheses). Posting the data t 8888 the web somewhere and providing a URL may be necessary. If the data can't be released to the public at large but could be shared at all, then you may be able to offer to e-mail it to interested parties (although this will cut down the number of people who will bother to work on it). I haven't actually seen this 4444 done, because people who can't release their data are sensitive about releasing it any form, but it would seem plausible that in some cases one could still post data if it were sufficiently anonymized/scrambled/corrupted slightly in some way. If you can't do either of these then you probably need to hire a consultant to solve your problem", 
            "You are 888 most 1g likely to get good 5g help with your R problem if you provide a reproducible example. A reproducible example allows someone else to recreate your problem by just copying and pasting R code. There are four things you need to include to make your example reproducible: required packages, data, code, and a description of your R environment. Packages should be loaded at the top of the script, so it's easy to see which ones the example needs. The easiest way to include data in an email is to use dput() to generate the R code to recreate it. For example, to recreate the mtcars dataset in R, I'd perform the following steps: Run dput(mtcars) in R Copy the output In my reproducible script, type mtcars <- then paste. Spend a little bit of time ensuring that your code is easy for others to read: make sure you've used spaces and your variable names are concise, but informative, use comments to indicate where your problem lies, do your best to remove everything that is not related to the problem. The shorter your code is, the easier it is to understand. Include the output of sessionInfo() as a comment. This summarises your R environment and makes it easy to check if you're using an out-of-date package. You can check you have actually made a reproducible example by starting up a fresh R session and pasting your script in. Before putting all of your code in an email, consider putting it on http://gist.github.com/. It will give your code nice syntax highlighting, and you don't have to worry about anything getting mangled by the email system.",
            "Do your homework before posting: If it is clear that you have done basic background research, you are far more likely to get an informative response. See also Further Resources further down this page. Do help.search(keyword) and apropos(keyword) with different keywords (type this at the R prompt). Do RSiteSearch(keyword) with different keywords (at the R prompt) to search R functions, contributed packages and R-Help postings. See ?RSiteSearch for further options and to restrict searches. Read the online help for relevant functions (type ?functionname, e.g., ?prod, at the R prompt) If something seems to have changed in R, look in the latest NEWS file on CRAN for information about it. Search the R-faq and the R-windows-faq if it might be relevant (http://cran.r-project.org/faqs.html) Read at least the relevant section in An Introduction to R If the function is from a package accompanying a book, e.g., the MASS package, consult the book before posting. The R Wiki has a section on finding functions and documentation",
            "Before 6g asking a technical question by e-mail, or in a newsgroup, or on a website chat board, do the following:  Try to find an answer by searching the archives of the forum you plan to post to. Try to find an answer by searching the Web. Try to find an answer by reading the manual. Try to find an answer by reading a FAQ. Try to find an answer by inspection or experimentation. Try to find an answer by asking a skilled friend. If you're a programmer, try to find an answer by reading the source code. When you ask your question, display the fact that you have done these things first; this will help establish that you're not being a lazy sponge and wasting people's time. Better yet, display what you have learned from doing these things. We like answering questions for people who have demonstrated they can learn from the answers. Use tactics like doing a Google search on the text of whatever error message you get (searching Google groups as well as Web pages). This might well take you straight to fix documentation or a mailing list thread answering your question. Even if it doesn't, saying “I googled on the following phrase but didn't get anything that looked promising” is a good thing to do in e-mail or news postings requesting help, if only because it records what searches won't help. It will also help to direct other people with similar problems to your thread by linking the search terms to what will hopefully be your problem and resolution thread. Take your time. Do not expect to be able to solve a complicated problem with a few seconds of Googling. Read and understand the FAQs, sit back, relax and give the problem some thought before approaching experts. Trust us, they will be able to tell from your questions how much reading and thinking you did, and will be more willing to help if you come prepared. Don't instantly fire your whole arsenal of questions just because your first search turned up no answers (or too many). Prepare your question. Think it through. Hasty-sounding questions get hasty answers, or none at all. The more you do to demonstrate that having put thought and effort into solving your problem before seeking help, the more likely you are to actually get help. Beware of asking the wrong question. If you ask one that is based on faulty assumptions, J. Random Hacker is quite likely to reply with a uselessly literal answer while thinking Stupid question..., and hoping the experience of getting what you asked for rather than what you needed will teach you a lesson.")
dtm <- dfm(examp, removePunct = TRUE, removeNumbers = TRUE)
as.TermDocumentMatrix(as.DocumentTermMatrix(dtm))
# <<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 469, documents: 5)>>
# Non-/sparse entries: 652/1693
# Sparsity           : 72%
# Maximal term length: 18
# Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
```

Comment: How can I work it into a function like follows: `gram2Tokenizer <- function(x) {RWeka::NGramTokenizer(x, RWeka::Weka_control(min = 2, max = 2))}` and use it like so:`tdm2<- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus, control = list(tokenize=gram2Tokenizer))`?

Comment: To create a document-term matrix, you can just use `dfm(txt)` and by default, `removeNumbers = TRUE`. Or, for more control, you can call `dfm(myTokenizedTexts)` after tokenising as above. Note that quanteda only does document-term matrixes, not tdms.

Comment: Is it possible to a covert a document term matrix to a term document then? If so how? Can you give a full script example?

Comment: You can wrap it in `as.TermDocumentMatrix(as.DocumentTermMatrix(dfm))`. The inner call is a quanteda function, the outer is tm. See edits above.